# Python : Appending values to existing spreadsheet from updated values

Tags: python, excel, append, rows

## What is working now

In the code below, the first 100 rows are getting downloaded to Futures.xlsx from the website.

The website updates every 15 minutes refreshing new values just like a company stock. Total rows are 100.

How can I modify my code such as every time a website updates or through some counter continue adding 100 more updated values to Futures.xlsx file. So I would say over one hour there would be 400 Rows.

I have included first four lines of the code output.

## Output

```
   Contracts    Markets     Open    High    Low    Last     Pct     Time
0  Oct 2018 (E)    NG.F27.E    2.777   2.785   2.774   2.782   +0.36%  20:00
1  Nov 2018 (E)    NG.F27.E    2.793   2.800   2.792   2.800   +0.32%  19:51
2  Dec 2018 (E)    NG.F27.E    2.887   2.893   2.886   2.891   +0.21%  19:52
3  Jan 2019 (E)    NG.F27.E    2.977   2.984   2.975   2.980   +0.20%  19:52
```

## Code

```
 urllib.request import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import ExcelWriter
 from pandas import ExcelFile
 import os

 url = "https://quotes.ino.com/exchanges/contracts.html?r=NYMEX_NG"
 res = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

 Markets = []
 Contracts =[]
 Opens =[]
 Highs =[]
 Lows =[]
 Lasts=[]
 Changes=[]
 Pcts=[]

 data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[3:]

 for td in data_rows[:100]:
 Market = td.findAll ('td')[0].text
 Markets.append(Market)
 Contract = td.findAll('td')[1].text
 Contracts.append(Contract)
 Open = td.findAll('td')[2].text
 Opens.append(Open)
 High = td.findAll('td')[3].text
 Highs.append(High)
 Low = td.findAll('td')[4].text
 Lows.append(Low)
 Last = td.findAll('td')[5].text
 Lasts.append(Last)
 Change = td.findAll('td')[6].text
 Changes.append(Change)
 Pct = td.findAll('td')[7].text
 Pcts.append(Pct)
 Time = td.findAll('td')[8].text

 df = pd.DataFrame({'Contracts' :Contracts,    Markets':Market,'Open':Opens, 
           'High':Highs, 'Low':Lows,'Last':Lasts,'Pct':Pcts})

out_path = "C:\Sid\Futures.xls"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path , engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the time.sleep method to set a timer for every 15 minutes. You can set up a small function to refresh the program for you, which I have done below.

```
def RefreshProgram(Program, timespan):
    while Program.isRunning:
        program.refresh()
        sleep(900)
```

Below would be how you could go about saving your excel data. `datalist` would be a row of data that was taken from your web page.

```
logbook=pxl.load_workbook(file_location_goes_here, data_only=False)

emptylist=['','','','','','']

ash=logbook["name_of_sheet_goes_here"]

datalist=[data_from_webpage]

#defining row, column, and checking cell data

    rowx = 1
    colx = 1
    cellcontent = ash.cell(row=rowx, column=colx).value

    #finding first empty row           
    while cellcontent != None:
        rowx += 1
        cellcontent= ash.cell(row=rowx, column=colx).value

    for data in datalist:
        ash.cell(row=rowx, column=colx).value = data
        colval += 1

    logbook.save(filelocation)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. It would be one of the step.However, my main concern is the excel file with updated rows. 100 for first 15 minutes, another 100 for next 15 minutes and so on.

Comment: @SiddharthKulkarni How long do you want the set to last? Do you want it to reset every hour or go on forever? I can help with excel but just need to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate it. I would say one hour max for a day. I can try to do iterations later once I get a general idea from you.

Comment: @SiddharthKulkarni I have updated my code. I'm sure it seems confusing but if you have any questions, just ask. I'm here to help. Also, if you could choose my answer for the answer to your question, I would be thankful.

Comment: Thanks for the code. In your code do I insert my Datalist = [df], my dataframe? The reason I ask is will your code identify empty cells in excel and automatically post row level data from my dataframe?

Comment: @SiddharthKulkarni Yes, it should. The code may need to be tweaked but for the most part, it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @SiddharthKulkarni There is a check mark under the score for my answer. Please click it to select my answer as the best and mark this question solved. I will continue to help if you need more.

Comment: @FanManWhat syntax is needed to initialize your code. For eg. Import ? I am getting error such as rowcontent not defined.

Comment: @SiddharthKulkarni In the while loop, change rowcontent to cellcontent

Comment: Getting the error                                                                                               
    205             raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

Comment: @SiddharthKulkarni I'm not here to write your code for you. I'm here to help but you want me to write your code for you.

Comment: I was almost trying your code for two hours yesterday. Since I am not having luck I am sorry I cannot accept your answer. But, I sincerely appreciate you stepping in and offering your help. Atleast for the timer.